# jScrollPane stopped working, and I can't see why

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

On this page:
http://ally.alchemycs.com
there is a box in the middle of the page labeled "Screenings" that has scrollbars.  A while ago, I set up jScrollPane so that it had nice pretty scrollbars that matched the design.  jScrollPane has mysteriously stopped working, and for the life of me, I can't see why.  jQuery is there, jScrollPane CSS and JS is there, I don't see any error messages in FireBug.  What's really aggravating is that this was working a while ago, and I don't think anything has changed that should have interfered with it.

Can anyone else see why jScrollPane isn't working here?

Comment: [02:30:44.991] Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [type="text/javascript"],not([type]) @ http://ally.alchemycs.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3:2 - getting this on visiting

Comment: which probably means you have added some faulty jQuery code recently^

Comment: The problem file is actually called `jquery.js`

Comment: As Daniel mentioned, I also have that error + Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'

Comment: something is wrong with your jquery.js file which is needed for jscrollpane to work, maybe try pulling it from a cdn

Comment: Did you edit your jquery.js file? because the only difference between yours and from jquery.com site is that you added `jQuery.noConflict();` at the end of the file ... wonder if that is creating the conflict. Try loading jQuery with this line instead : `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`

Comment: That's weird... I didn't edit jquery.js, and I'm pretty sure that when I updated WordPress on this site, WordPress's latest version of jquery was loaded.  In any case, I am now pulling jquery from Google, and still have the same problem.

Comment: The "Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'" is caused by something in the Vimeo iframe, and taking it out doesn't help the jScrollPane issue.